# UIButton layer Issue

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uibutton

I have created `UIView` on navigation bar which drop downs with animation and below navigation bar I have created another button. In `UIView` I have created three buttons in a row. Now when view opens, it comes on bottom. So whenever I click on `UIView's` button it get clicks on button which is on back of view. Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Comment: I am not too much getting what is your problem can you please give me brief explain your problem?

Comment: Is the UIView that drops down embedded into the navigation bar, or is it just positioned over it?

Comment: @Pranav Please explain your question properly...

Answer (score 0):

When the animated UIView drops down try disabling the UIButton that is behind it.

```
UIButton* button...
button.userInteraction = NO;
```